# Class property returns nil

Tags: swift, class, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, properties

I'm working with `FirebaseDatabase` to store data. I have a simple model that transforms the `snapshot` data into a `post`. The problem is that after observing the `snapshot`, the property called `postType` returns `nil` and I cannot figure out why.

```
class Post {

    var id           : String?
    var title        : String?
    var content      : String?
    var source       : String?
    var userUid      : String?
    var type         : PostType?
}

extension Post {

    static func transformDataToImagePost (dictionary: [String : Any], key: String) -> Post {
        let post = Post()
        post.id        = key
        post.userUid   = dictionary["userUid"] as? String
        post.title     = dictionary["title"] as? String
        post.content   = dictionary["content"] as? String
        post.source    = dictionary["source"] as? String
        post.type = dictionary["postType"] as? PostType

        return post
    }


enum PostType: String {

    case image = "image"
    case gif = "gif"
    case video = "video"
    case text = "text"
    case link = "link"
    case audio = "audio"
    case poll = "poll"
    case chat = "chat"
    case quote = "quote"
}


func observePost(withId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void) {
    REF_POSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            print(snapshot.value) // <- ["key":value, "postType": text, "key": value]
            print(dictionary["postType"]) // <- returns text
            let post = Post.transformDataToImagePost(dictionary: dictionary, key: snapshot.key)
            print(post.type)  // <- returns nil
            completion(post)
        }
    })
}
```

I just cannot figure out why the `post.type` returns `nil`

Comment: Are you sure that `postType` return from Firebase suit with the enum ?
please post more code to see what you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Post.type` is a `enum`, You can't just set it to a String. What you have is the equivalent of: `post.type = "text"`

Try to initialise it this way:

```
post.type = PostType(rawValue: dictionary["postType"])
```

You may need to unwrap the value first.

```
if let postType = dictionary["postType"] as? String {
     post.type = PostType(rawValue: postType)
}
```

Example of how to init an enum like this in a playground:

```
enum PostType: String {

    case image = "image"
    case gif = "gif"
    case video = "video"
    case text = "text"
    case link = "link"
    case audio = "audio"
    case poll = "poll"
    case chat = "chat"
    case quote = "quote"
}

let postType = PostType(rawValue: "poll")
print(postType)
```

> **Output** Optional(__lldb_expr_339.PostType.poll)

You can read more about enums in the [Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html). For this particular issue; look for the heading: "Initializing from a Raw Value"